# PASCAL: need help understanding. writeln(1st, ' ', x:10. ' ', fitness:6:4);

Tags: pascal

I am new to pascal and trying to convert a body of code from a GA book to java.

```
writeln(1st, ' ', x:10. ' ', fitness:6:4);
```

I am not sure what the 1st means initially.
Also the :10 and :6:4 following the two variables.

Any help in making me understand would be appreciated.

Comment: `1st` does not seem valid (idents can't start with a digit). `x:10` means `x` in a 10 character wide field, `fitness:6:4` means `fitness` in a 6 character wide field with 4 decimal places (float variable assumed).

Comment: Terrific, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

That code looks full of typos to me. Did you type it correctly or is it that bad in practice?

1st is an invalid variable name, so perhaps it's a string literal and should be in quotes?

x:10 is x formatted to a fixed 10 character length and right justified. e.g. if x = 'hi' the output would be

```
'        hi'
```

The full stop, I assume should be a comma, otherwise you have a syntax error.

fitness:6:4 is fitness formatted to a 6 character field and 4 decimal places. For example 3.141592

```
'3.1415'
```

Potentially (And I'm guessing here) the correct code should look like this:

```
writeln('1st', ' ', x:10, ' ', fitness:6:4);
```

As an example output

```
x = 'hi'
fitness = 3.141592

output:
   '1st         hi 3.1415'
```